# How to create a dynamic page jump

Tags: php, html

I am trying to create a dynamic page jump.
I know how to create a page jump for example

```
<a href="#example">example</a>
<a name="example">example1</a>
```

I have a products page that echo's everything out using a string from the database, product category, name and description; and i also have another set of product category names which print separately. I want to match up the product categories so if the user clicks on the category names that are printed separately, the page will jump and take the user to correct start of the page.

like the Deliveroo website. [click here](https://deliveroo.co.uk/menu/london/bloomsbury/mantovani-1946)

At the moment when clicking on the separate category name the page jumps but not to the correct category name. It just keeps jumping to the first category name listed.

**My code**

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_INDEX);
if (isset($_GET['rest_id'])) {
    $R = $_GET['rest_id'];
    $g_cat = "SELECT * FROM Food_Cat WHERE Resturant_ID = '$R'";
    $runn_g_cat = mysqli_query($dbc, $g_cat);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($runn_g_cat);
    echo("<div id='get_cats'>");
    $iiii=1;
    while ($row_g_cat = mysqli_fetch_array($runn_g_cat)) {
        $Food_Cat_name = $row_g_cat['Food_Cat_name'];

        echo("<a id='show_cats' href='#foodcat$iiii'>$Food_Cat_name</p>");
        $iiii=1;
    }
}
```

...

```
while ($row_get_cat = mysqli_fetch_array($run_get_cat)) {
    $category_name = $row_get_cat['Food_Cat_name'];
    $food_id = $row_get_cat['Food_Cat_ID'];

    echo("<div id='cat_name' class='cat_name'>");
    echo("<a name='foodcat$iiii' id='categ_nme'>$category_name</p>");
    echo("<hr id='line'>");
    $iii++;
}
```

The entire code is very long but works, i have error handlers, sessions are set and the queries work.

Answer (score 1):

In the first part of the code you have this code:

```
$iiii=1;
while ($row_g_cat = mysqli_fetch_array($runn_g_cat)) {
    /* ... */
    $iiii=1;
}
```

This should be `$iii++;` like below.

Comment: `$iiii` is defined before that while loop, althought you are correct it does need to be incremented

Comment: Thank you. i do not know how i over looked that. but now it does not jump at all

Comment: @ShamSUP could you please explain, sorry I'm a newbee

Comment: `$iiii=1;
while ($row_g_cat = mysqli_fetch_array($runn_g_cat)) {
    $iiii++;
}`
You have to increment your `$iiii` variable. When you applied these changes it's likely that you didn't change the other ocurrences of `$iiii` to `$iii`, just check for consistency between all your variable names.